# How to add a logic statement to an object entering a moving area

Tags: javascript, if-statement, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a game. The object of the game is to move the square across the screen without hitting a raindrop falling from the roof. How do i make it so that if one of the raindrops enters the square, the square returns to the beginning of the canvas or x =0. Here is the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var WIDTH = 1000;
var HEIGHT = 700;
var x = 0;
var y = HEIGHT-20;
var xPos = [0];
var yPos = [0];
var speed = [1];
var rainDrops = 50;
var rectWidth = 20;
var rectHeight = 20;






for (var i = 0; i < rainDrops; i++) {
    xPos.push(Math.random()* WIDTH);
    yPos.push(0);
    speed.push(Math.random() * 5);

    }



function rainFall () {

    window.requestAnimationFrame(rainFall);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);



    for (var i = 0; i <rainDrops; i++) {
    //Rain
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(xPos[i], yPos[i], 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fill();

    //Rain movement
    yPos[i]+=speed[i];

    //Box

        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, rectWidth, rectWidth);

    if (yPos[i] > HEIGHT) {
        yPos[i]= 0;
        yPos[i]+=speed[0];
        }
    //This is the part where I need the Help!!!!!!!!!
    if (){
        x = 0;
    }

    }


};



//Move Object

function move (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        ctx.clearRect (0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        x -=10;
    }
    if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        ctx.clearRect (0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        x+=10;
    }
    canvas.width=canvas.width

}




//Lockl Screen

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    // Lock arrow keys
    if( [37,39,].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);


rainFall(); 
document.onkeydown = move;
window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

Comment: I figured it out

Comment: if (xPos[i]>=x && xPos[i] <= x +rectWidth && yPos[i] >= y && yPos[i] <= y + rectHeight){
  x = 0;
  }

Comment: Cool, just before I posted an answer. Always better working out for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Conditional statements

I am never too sure how to answer these types of questions. As you are a beginner I don't want to overwhelm you with code and techniques, but at the same time I don't want to give an answer that perpetuates some bad techniques.

#### The short answer

So first the simple answer from your code where you wrote

```
//This is the part where I need the Help!!!!!!!!!
// the test checks the center of the drop 
// if drop is greater than > top of player (y) and (&&) 
// drop x  greater than > left side of player x and (&&) drop is less than <
// right side of player (x + rectWidth) then drop has hit player   
if (yPos[i] > y && xPos[i] > x && xPos[i] < x + rectWidth ){
    x = 0; // move player back
}
```

BTW you are drawing the player rectangle for each rain drop. You should move that draw function outside the loop.

#### The long answer

Hopefully I have not made it too confusing and have added plenty of comments about why I did this and that.

To help keep everything organised I separate out the various elements into their own objects. There is the `player`, `rain`, and keyboard handler. This is all coordinated via the `mainLoop` the is called once a frame (by `requestAnimationFrame`) and calls the various functions to do all that is needed.

The `player` object holds all the data to do with the player, and functions to `draw` and `update` the player (update moves the player)

The `rain` object holds all the rain in an array called `rain.drops` it has functions to `draw` and `update` the rain. It also has some functions to randomize a drop, and add new drops.

To test if the rain has hit the player I do it in the `rain.update` function (where I move the rain) I don`t know what you wanted to happen when the rain hits the player so I just reset the rain drop and added 1 to the hit counter.

I first check if the bottom of the rain drop `drop.y + drop.radius` is greater than the top of the player `if(drop.y + drop.radius >= player.y){`

This makes it so we dont waste time checking rain that is above the player.

The I test for the rain in the x direction. The easiest is the test the negative (if the rain is not hitting the player) as the logic is a little simplier.

If the right side of the drop is to the left of the left side of the player, or (use || for or) the left side of the drop is to the right of the right side of the player than the drop can not be hitting the player. As we want the reverse condition we wrap it in a brackets a put a not in front `if(! ( ... ) )`

The test is a little long so I break it into 2 lines for readability.

```
 // drop is a single rain drop player is the player
 if (drop.y + drop.radius >= player.y) {
     if ( ! (drop.x + drop.radius < player.x || 
     drop.x - drop.radius > player.x + player.width) ) { 
         // code for player hit by rain in here
     }
 }
```

The `rain.update` function also checks if the rain has hit the bottom of the canvas and resets it if so.

#### Demo

I copied your code from in the question and modified it.

```js
addEventListener("load",function(){  // you had onload at the bottom after all the code that gets the canvas
                                     // etc. Which kind of makes the on load event pointless. Though not needed
                                     // in this example I have put it in how you can use it for a web page.
                                     // Using onload event lets you put the javascript anywhere in the HTML document
                                     // if you dont use onload you must then only put the javascript after
                                     // the page elements you need eg Canvas.
    var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.font = "20px arial";
    var frameCount = 0; // counts the frames

    var WIDTH = canvas.width;
    var HEIGHT = canvas.height;    
    var currentMaxDrops = 5; // rain will increase over time
    const numberFramesPerRainIncrease = 60 * 5; // long name says it all. 60 frames is one second.
    const maxRainDrops = 150;  // max number of rain drops
    
    // set up keyboard handler
    addEventListener("keydown", keyEvent);
    addEventListener("keyup", keyEvent);    
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // request the first frame of the animation (get it all going)

    //==========================================================================================
    // Setup the keyboard input stuff
    const keys = {  // list of keyboard keys to listen to by name. 
        ArrowLeft : false,
        ArrowRight : false,
    }
    function keyEvent(event){  // the key event argument event.code hold the named key.
        if(keys[event.code] !== undefined){   // is this a key we want
            event.preventDefault();  // prevent default browser action
            keys[event.code] = event.type === "keydown";  // true if keydown false if not
        }
    }


    //==========================================================================================
    const player = {  // object for everything to do with the player
        x : 0,           // position
        y : HEIGHT - 20,  
        width : 20,      // size
        height : 20,      
        speed : 4,       // speed per frame
        color : "red",
        showHit : 0,  // when this is > 0 then draw the player blue to indicate a hit. 
                      // This counter is counted down each frame  so setting its value 
                      // determins how long to flash the blue
        hitCount : 0,   // a count of the number of drops that hit the player.
        status(){  // uses hit count to get a status string 
            if(player.hitCount === 0){
                return "Dry as a bone.";
            }
            if(player.hitCount < 5){
                return "A little damp.";
            }
            if(player.hitCount < 15){
                return "Starting to get wet.";
            }
            return "Soaked to the core";
        },
        draw(){  // draw the player
           if(player.showHit > 0){
               player.showHit -= 1; // count down show hit
               ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
           }else{
               ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
           }
           ctx.fillRect(player.x,player.y,player.width,player.height);
        },
        update(){ // this updates anything to do with the player
           // Not sure how you wanted movement. You had it so that you move only when key down events
           // so I have done the same
           if(keys.ArrowLeft){
               player.x -= player.speed;  // move to the left
               keys.ArrowLeft = false; // turn off the key. If you remove this line then will move left while       
                                       // the key is down and stop when the key is up.
               if(player.x < 0){ // is the player on or past left side of canvas
                    player.x = 0; // move player back to zero.
               }
           }
           if(keys.ArrowRight){
               player.x += player.speed;  // move to the right
               keys.ArrowRight = false; // turn off the key. If you remove this line then will move right while       
                                       // the key is down and stop when the key is up.
               
               if(player.x + player.width >= WIDTH){ // is the player on or past right side of canvas
                    player.x = WIDTH - player.width; // move player back to inside the canvas.
               }
           }
        }
            
    }

    //==========================================================================================
    const rain = {  // object to hold everything about rain
        numberRainDrops : 50,
        drops : [],  // an array of rain drops.
        randomizeDrop(drop){ // sets a drop to random position etc.
            drop.x = Math.random() * WIDTH;  // random pos on canvas
            drop.y = -10;                      // move of screen a little so we dont see it just appear
            drop.radius = Math.random() *3 + 1; // give the drops a little random size
            drop.speed = Math.random() * 4 + 1; // and some speed Dont want 0 speed so add 1
            return drop;
        },
        createDrop(){  // function to create a rain drop and add it to the array of drops
            if(rain.drops.length < currentMaxDrops){ // only add if count is below max
                rain.drops.push(rain.randomizeDrop({})); // create and push a drop. {} creates an empty object that the function
                                                    // randomizeDrop will fill with the starting pos of the drop.
                rain.numberRainDrops = rain.drops.length;
            }
        },
        draw(){    // draw all the rain
            ctx.beginPath();  // start a new path
            ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';  // set the colour
            for(var i = 0; i < rain.drops.length; i ++){
                var drop = rain.drops[i]; // get the indexed drop
                ctx.arc(drop.x, drop.y, drop.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.closePath(); // stops the drops rendered as one shape
            }        
            ctx.fill();    // now draw all the drops.        
        },
        update(){
            for(var i = 0; i < rain.drops.length; i ++){
                var drop = rain.drops[i]; // get the indexed drop
                drop.y += drop.speed;     // move down a bit.
                if(drop.y + drop.radius >= player.y){ // is this drop at or below player height
                     // checks if the drop is to the left or right of the player
                     // as we want to know if the player is hit we use ! (not)
                     // Thus the next if statement is if rain is not to the left or to the right then 
                     // it must be on the player.
                     if(!(drop.x + drop.radius < player.x || // is the rigth side of the drop left of the players left side
                        drop.x - drop.radius > player.x + player.width)){ 
                        // rain has hit the player.
                        player.hitCount += 1;
                        player.showHit += 5;
                        rain.randomizeDrop(drop); // reset this drop.
                     }
                }
                if(drop.y > HEIGHT + drop.radius){ // is it off the screen ?
                      rain.randomizeDrop(drop); // restart the drop 
                }
            }        
        }
    }
            
    function mainLoop () {  // main animation loop
        requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);  // request next frame (don`t need to specify window as it is the default object)
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frameCount += 1; // count the frames
        // when the remainder of frame count and long name var is 0 increase rain drop count
        if(frameCount % numberFramesPerRainIncrease === 0){
            if(currentMaxDrops < maxRainDrops){
               currentMaxDrops += 1;
            }
        }
        
        rain.createDrop(); // a new drop (if possible) per frame
        rain.update();  // move the rain and checks if the player is hit
        player.update();   // moves the player if keys are down and check if play hits the side of the canvas
        player.draw();   // draw player
        rain.draw();  // draw rain after player so its on top.
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillText("Hit " + player.hitCount + " times.",5,20);
        ctx.setTransform(0.75,0,0,0.75,5,34); // makes status font 3/4 size and set position to 5 34 so I dont have to work out where to draw the smaller font
        ctx.fillText(player.status(),0,0); // the transform set the position so text is just drawn at 0,0
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset the transform to the default so all other rendering is not effected
    };

});
```

```css
canvas {
   border : 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width=512 height=200></canvas>
```

Hope this was helpfull.

Comment: Fantastic! Yes I am a beginner. I am trying to teach myself how to code and this is my first project. I tried out the code you left and its great. Just curious, how long does it take to be able to write so fluidly like that. Most of the time I try and figure things out with less code in hopes that it makes it easier to break down but my goal is to be able to master object orientation.

Comment: Also, they way you wrote out the code and broke things into objects showed me how I should approach writing code for now on

Comment: @cez A few years of practice will get you to a level so that you can cover most types of application development .Learning the language and syntax is easy, gaining the experience to write bug free and quickly can take some time. As long as you enjoy it (the most important part of becoming a good programer) you will continue to improve. I have been writing code for 37 years and I am still learning, and still enjoy creating.